# NPOI copy range to another worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, copy, range, npoi

I am using NPOI to work with Excel in C#. But there is no full documentation how to work with it. I need to copy some range to another worksheet. Does anybody know, how to do this? Maybe you are using another dll(not interop) to provide such functionality. If so, please tell me.

In excel everything is very simple:

```
Worksheets(2).rows(2).copy newsheet.Range("A1")
```

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 6):

NPOI doesn't support this out of the box but the implementation is straightforward.
Two functions are of interest here: `CopyColumn()` and `CopyRange()`.

`CopyRangeExample()` opens a workbook, creates a new output sheet and copies cells (data and style) from one sheet to another.

```
void CopyRangeExample()
{
  var workbook = OpenWorkbook("test.xlsx");

  var destinationSheetName = "destination" + (workbook.NumberOfSheets + 1).ToString();
  workbook.CreateSheet(destinationSheetName);

  ISheet sourceSheet = workbook.GetSheet("source");
  ISheet destinationSheet = workbook.GetSheet(destinationSheetName);

  CopyColumn("I", sourceSheet, destinationSheet);
  CopyRange(CellRangeAddress.ValueOf("C6:E15"), sourceSheet, destinationSheet);

  SaveWorkbook(workbook, "test.xlsx");
}
```

And the rest of the code:

```
void CopyRange(CellRangeAddress range, ISheet sourceSheet, ISheet destinationSheet)
{
  for (var rowNum = range.FirstRow; rowNum <= range.LastRow; rowNum++)
  {
    IRow sourceRow = sourceSheet.GetRow(rowNum);

    if (destinationSheet.GetRow(rowNum)==null)
      destinationSheet.CreateRow(rowNum);

    if (sourceRow != null)
    {
      IRow destinationRow = destinationSheet.GetRow(rowNum);

      for (var col = range.FirstColumn; col < sourceRow.LastCellNum && col<=range.LastColumn; col++)
      {
        destinationRow.CreateCell(col);
        CopyCell(sourceRow.GetCell(col), destinationRow.GetCell(col));
      }
    }
  }
}

void CopyColumn(string column, ISheet sourceSheet, ISheet destinationSheet)
{
  int columnNum = CellReference.ConvertColStringToIndex(column);
  var range = new CellRangeAddress(0, sourceSheet.LastRowNum, columnNum, columnNum);
  CopyRange(range, sourceSheet, destinationSheet);
}

void CopyCell(ICell source, ICell destination)
{
  if (destination != null && source != null)
  {
    //you can comment these out if you don't want to copy the style ...
    destination.CellComment = source.CellComment;
    destination.CellStyle = source.CellStyle;
    destination.Hyperlink = source.Hyperlink;

    switch (source.CellType)
    {
        case CellType.Formula:
            destination.CellFormula = source.CellFormula; break;
        case CellType.Numeric:
            destination.SetCellValue(source.NumericCellValue); break;
        case CellType.String:
            destination.SetCellValue(source.StringCellValue); break;
    }
  }
}

IWorkbook OpenWorkbook(string path)
{
  IWorkbook workbook;
  using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
  {
    workbook = WorkbookFactory.Create(fileStream);
  }
  return workbook;
}

void SaveWorkbook(IWorkbook workbook, string path)
{
  using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
  {
    workbook.Write(fileStream);
  }
}
```

Just remember to include NPOI and System.IO in your project:

```
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
using NPOI.SS.Util;
using System.IO;
```